# Having doubt in a couple of metaphorical statements

Tags: grammar, metaphors

I am having slight doubt with a couple of metaphorical statements. A slight assistance will be most welcome.

1."The insatiable desire to breakout becomes the carnival of the oppressed, an iconic symbol of that ray of hope that sustains the power of imagination and reclaims the space for freedom and the dream of reality where the past meets the future in the present."

What does this statement really mean?

2."The cloud is not fenced in like many threatened by death behind a razor-sharp fence that is reproduced globally, in every continent, in every nation, in every state. However, at the back of my mind, I can feel the hidden bazooka-like cameras revealing sorrowfully the apprehensive face of a mother."

What are bazooka like cameras really meant in this context?

Comment: You need to provide the source of your quote.

Answer (score 0):

1. The need/want/hope to be set free is the obsessive dream that haunts but also cherishes oppressed people.

---

2. Camera's with telescopic lenses that stick out a long way, The silhouette of the person using such a cameras being similar to that of someone using a bazooka. In more modern times or by a younger writer probably an RPG, which is not quite the same but similar would be used as the analogy.

---

Comment: What is meant by past meets future?

Comment: @Knowledge Seeker the present.  It is trying to relate people thinking of the past, dreaming of the future but they are in the reality of the present

Comment: What is past and what is future in the context?

Comment: I am having slight doubt with a couple of metaphorical statements. Was the title of this exploration, now I know why, do not expect things to be laid out like for science exam.

Comment: Could not get you.